# validate destruction of has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Models:

```
class Factory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :factory_workers
  has_many :workers, through: :factory_workers
end

class FactoryWorkers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :factory
  belongs_to :worker

  before_destroy :union_approves?

  private

  def union_approves?
    errors.add(:proletariat, "is never destroyed!")

    false
  end
end

class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :factory_workers
  has_many :factorys, through: :factory_workers
end
```

If I attempt to update a Factory's list of Workers via Factory, and that leads to the destruction of some FactoryWorker associations, I hope that the before_destroy hook is called, but this does not seem to be the case.

Example

```
Factory.create(name: 'communist paradise', worker_ids: [1, 2])

Factory.find_by(name: 'commnist paradise').update(worker_ids: [1])
# before_destroy hook is not called, proletariat must riot!
```

How can I ensure the before_destory hook is called when updating a record's associations?

Comment: before_destory is called before destroy method. Don't you mean before_update?

Comment: @Michal I want to make sure the before_destroy method is called on the "through" model, FactoryWorkers, if updating the parent model, Factory, results in a FactoryWorker record being destroyed. Check out my example at the bottom of my post. Note that calling .update with fewer worker_ids than before will result in the destruction of a FactoryWorker record, but ActiveRecord does not seem to call the before_destroy hook (likely because it isn't instantiating a FactoryWorker instance).

Comment: You really shouldn't be making any reference to object IDs in the way that you do in your example. Rails has quite sophisticated methods for interacting with associations to avoid you needing to mess about with the IDs of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I needed: ActiveRecord provides a before_remove method on associations, so I just need to rejigger as follows:

```
class Factory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workers, before_remove: :union_approves?

  private

  def union_approves?
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: returning `false` prevents workers from being removed but `errors.add` there does not add validation errors.